USB 2.0 Super Extender Issue
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and attempting to run a CAEN DT5790 digitizer over a USB 2.0 super extender 4 port hub that extends the USB link over an ethernet cable, and I haven't been able to see the device with "lsusb" when I plug it into the extender. I have previously successfully used a USB extender cable to connect to the device to my laptop.
According to the extender hub's manual there should be no extra drivers to install, it's supposed to be plug and play - has anyone had experience with the "ekl usb 2.0 super extender" in Ubuntu?
